# Problems in ResourceIntensiveTask in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, background-task

I am developing a Windows Phone application that can update the tile with time in `HH:mm:ss` format. I have tested with PeriodicTask, which updates the tile for 30 mins and for 30 seconds in debugging conditions. So, I found ResourceIntensiveTask seems useful to me, when certain conditions met, they update as soon as possible (I got this knowledge from http://jesseliberty.com/2011/10/05/background-agents/) , so I have programmed like below in ScheduledAgent.cs

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{                
    StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData
    {
        Title = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss"),
        //BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Background.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
    };

    ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First().Update(data);      
#if DEBUG_AGENT     
    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
#endif
    NotifyComplete();      
}
```

and MainPage.xaml.cs as

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    agentsAreEnabled = true;

    periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(periodicTaskName) as ResourceIntensiveTask;

    if (periodicTask != null)
    {
        RemoveAgent(periodicTaskName);
    }

    periodicTask = new ResourceIntensiveTask(periodicTaskName);
    periodicTask.Description = "This checks for audio jack plugged in task.";

    try
    {
        ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
#if(DEBUG_AGENT)
        // If debugging is enabled, use LaunchForTest to launch the agent in one minute.
        ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
#endif
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
    {
        if (exception.Message.Contains("BNS Error: The action is disabled"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Background agents for this application have been disabled by the user.");
            agentsAreEnabled = false;
        }

        if (exception.Message.Contains("BNS Error: The maximum number of ScheduledActions of this type have already been added."))
        {
            // No user action required. The system prompts the user when the hard limit of periodic tasks has been reached.

        }

    }
    catch (SchedulerServiceException)
    {
        // No user action required.  
    }
}
```

Notice that I am using `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1)` instead of `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)` and I never implement to show time on tile in anywhere of the code, now when I run the app and pin the tile, it immeidately shows the time in HH:mm:ss format, but not updating. What might be the issue here. Am I on a correct track.

Remember, my device met all the conditions to run ResourceIntensiveTask and I am referring from [here](http://sportstoday.us/technology/windows-phone-8---background-agents-%28part-2%29---resource-intensive-agent.aspx) also as they mention about `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(taskName, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));`

Comment: The ResourceIntensiveTask is intended for long running processes like downloading data. You're using it to update the tile once and then finishing the task. I supposed you could run in a loop and keep updating the tile for half an hour.

Comment: I tried this by changing
`ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));` to
`for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
            }`

and `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));` to
`for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
                {
                    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
                }`
but it doesn't work :(

Comment: You are looping the launching of the task. I'm suggesting you could loop inside the task and do multiple tile updates.

Comment: can you please give me a code snippet please